# Best way to redirect with a different url an user from an old version to a new version of a Website

Tags: web-app, redirect

I have a web app based on an older web app which is going to be deprecated soon (databases no longer updated). 
What is the best way to redirect the user from the old web app to the new one ? I don't want to make the redirect without preventing, seems rough.

Thank you

Comment: 301 redirect: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Comment: @PaulDessert I don't want users to be redirect without being warned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not present a popup with the message and link to the new website?

> This website is soon going to be deprecate. Please visit our new
>   website.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I didn't know if it was too brutal for the user or not.. I guess there's no better way :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about redirecting automatically and *then* showing an option to return to the old one?

Google forums used to do that and I think it is a great alternative, because it makes the user see the new website (meaning that the users that are lazy to manually change to the new one could like the new one and prefer it) but still leaves the option to return to the old one.

I tried to capture an image to show you but it seems the Google Products Forum stopped showing it, but it was presented in a strong-background-colored topbar with a message that looked like:

> You are seeing the new version of the Google Products Forum. You can always **go back** to the old one. But why would you? :)

(I don't actually remember if there was a smile but you can have an idea).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but in my case the website is deprecate as it's no longer "powered" (not sure if you can say that in English) by the database

Comment: You could still do the automatic redirect - in fact, that might be a better option.